# GWT Autobeans / NoClassDefFoundError: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: gwt, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, autobean

I am trying to [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialize) a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POJO) to [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) in [GWT](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/) using [Autobeans](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean), an I keep receiving a [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) and [`ClassNotFoundException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html), both looking for [`org.json.JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html). This is in the context of tokenizing a [Place](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).

I created a JUnit test to isolate the problem. The test is:

```
@Test public void testGetToken() {
    SearchCriterion searchCriterion = new JavaSearchCriterion("a", "b", ImmutableList.of("c"));
    ResourcesPlace place = new ResourcesPlace(ImmutableList.of(searchCriterion));
    String token = new Tokenizer().getToken(place);
    assertNotNull(token);
}
```

And my stack trace is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter.quote(StringQuoter.java:69)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AutoBeanCodexImpl$PropertyGetter.encodeProperty(AutoBeanCodexImpl.java:411)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AutoBeanCodexImpl$PropertyGetter.visitValueProperty(AutoBeanCodexImpl.java:397)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.ProxyAutoBean.traverseProperties(ProxyAutoBean.java:260)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.traverse(AbstractAutoBean.java:166)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.accept(AbstractAutoBean.java:101)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AutoBeanCodexImpl.doEncode(AutoBeanCodexImpl.java:558)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanCodex.encode(AutoBeanCodex.java:83)
    at com.redacted.client.place.ResourcesPlace$Tokenizer.getToken(ResourcesPlace.java:62)
    at com.redacted.client.place.ResourcesPlaceTokenizerTest.testGetToken(ResourcesPlaceTokenizerTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 32 more
```

And here is the relevant bit of the Tokenizer:

```
    private MyFactory factory = AutoBeanFactorySource.create(MyFactory.class);

    interface MyFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
          // Factory method for a simple AutoBean
          AutoBean<SearchCriterion> person();

          // Factory method for a non-simple type or to wrap an existing instance
          AutoBean<SearchCriterion> person(SearchCriterion toWrap);
        }

    @Override
    public String getToken(ResourcesPlace place) {

        AutoBean<SearchCriterion> placeBean = factory.create(SearchCriterion.class, place.getSearchCriteria().get(0));
        return AutoBeanCodex.encode(placeBean).getPayload();
            }
```

I've added the Autobeans include in my .gwt.xml, but I still seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you launching the test runner?  Those classes originate from `gwt/tools/redist/json/r2_20080312/json-1.5.jar` in the GWT repo and should be packed into the `gwt-servlet-deps.jar`.  Try adding that jar to the classpath of your test run configuration to see if that clears it up.

Comment: That did the trick! For some reason, this jar did come from the Eclipse update site, so I had to go download it manually, and add it to the workspace/classpath.